# Entity Framework atypical 1-[0..1] -- model-only Association -- EF LINQ select possibilities

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one

Suppose the following tables

```
 ParentEntities
    ParentID

 ChildEntities
    ChildID
    ParentID
```

These tables do not have a FK defined in the schema.

In EF designer, after generating from DB, I add an association:

 - Parent Multiplicity: 1

 - Child Multiplicity: 0 or 1

When I build, I get the error: *"Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - ParentChild"*

But if I try to configure table mapping for the association like this..

```
Maps to ChildEntities 
  Parent
    ParentID <-> ParentID (parent entity prop <-> child table column)

  Child
    ChildID <-> ChildID (child entity prop <-> child table column)
```

.. I get this: *Error 3007: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines xxx, xxx: Column(s) [ParentID] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties.*

Why this is an error doesn't make sense. Limitation of the current implementation?

**[EDIT 1]**
I'm able to make this work by creating a 1-N association. That's not ideal, but it works just the same, just have to add a read-only child property in a partial:

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get { return Childs.Any() ? null : Childs.First(); } }
}
```

This seems like the best solution for me. I had to add a FK to the database to get EF to generate the association and navigation property, but once it was added I was able to remove the FK, and further updates to the model from the DB did not remove the association or Navigation properties.

**[EDIT 2]**
As I was investigating how to work around not caring about the association being modeled in EF, I ran into another issue. Instead of the read-only Child property I made it normal ..

```
public partial class Parent
{
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

.. but now I need a way to materialize that from the query:

```
var query = from parents in context.Parents
            // pointless join given select
            join child in context.Childs 
                on parents.ParentID equals child.ParentID
            select parents;
```

I can select an anonymous type ..

```
// step 1
var query = from parents in context.Parents
            join child in context.Childs
                on parents.ParentID equals child.ParentID
            select new { Parent = parents, Child = child };
```

.. but then I've got to consume more cycles getting that into my entity:

```
 // step 2
 var results = query.Select(x => {
                   var parent = x.Parent;
                   parent.Child = x.Child; 
                   return parent; });
```

Is there a better/streamlined way to do this from the query select so the EF materializer can do it from the get-go? If not, then I'll resort to Edit 1 methodology ..

Comment: If you go to Model Browser -> Model.Store, the relationship is probably different than what you have under Model, just delete the Model.Store table and re-add it.

Comment: @Bob, not sure I follow. How does deleting then re-adding the store table (which one?) change anything? I added both tables from the DB and there is no inherent relationship between the tables (nor one in the model). here is an image of my model.store http://j.mp/ZgE29p

Comment: There's a bug with EF where it doesn't like to refresh the `<database>.Store` for a EDMX when you change the model. So you have to find a way to refresh it.

Comment: what you're suggesting is a no-op/infinite loop. If I remove the table, I remove the model. If I re-add the table, it re-adds the model, and then I have to re-map the table AND the association, and then I'm back to square one with the error. I don't think this bug you're talking about is the culprit, or your work-around doesn't work.

Comment: No idea then, sorry. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ef Code first requires 1->0..1 relationships for the Child to have the same primary key.
Maybe this a similar restriction In the modeler in this circumstance. 
ParentId (Key) required in Both tables.

I have never tried adding such relationships in designer afterwords in DB first.

**EDIT: to match your EDIT2:**

I would stay on the direction . Use Navigation properties to get from Join back to original class A and B.

```
query = context.Set<JoinTable>.Where(Jt=>Jt.NavA.Id == ClassAId
                                  && Jt.navB.Id == ClassBId)
```

use a select if your need entries returned from either ClassA or ClassB.

Comment: After reading your answer, it occurred to me I could add the association as a 1-N, but that ran me into some other problems. I made some edits to the question, if you have any insight. Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't have a JoinTable though - just the 2: Parents, Childs, and no associations either, so no navigation properties (just a manually-added entity property in a partial extension class). Edit 2 was about finding a way to select out of the query a single Parent with that manually-added property populated with the results of the join materialized as Child entities

Comment: I use join tables with many to many cases.  Sorry no further ideas then

Comment: oh, sorry. this isn't a many to many situation. it's really 1-0..1. the DB simply doesn't have a FK, and the child 0..1 part doesn't share the PK of the Parent table. what I'm curious about is if there is a way to combine "// step 1" & "// step 2" from [EDIT 2] above

Comment: +1 for noting the EF limitations of 1->0..1 requiring same PKs